# Kivy update label after type

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Hellow im newbie on this. Im trying to send value to my screen class. I think im sending correctly but its not updating itself.I tought if i write things in .kv file , it does update for me. But im not sure how can i update new value to my label.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
Builder.load_string('''
<SM>:
    Page1:
        name: 'page1name'
<TestPop>:
    title: 'test pop title'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: test_textinput
        Button:
            text: 'Confirm'
            on_release: root.dismiss()
<Page1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Open Pop'
            on_release: root.func1()
        Label:
            text: root.my_label_string
''')
class Page1(Screen):
    my_label_string = StringProperty('Default')
    def func1(self):
        a = TestPop()
        a.open()
class TestPop(Popup):
    my_tinput_string = StringProperty('')
    def on_dismiss(self):
        new_text = self.ids.test_textinput.text
        Page1.my_label_string = new_text
class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SM()
if __name__ in ('__main__'):
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use

```
Page1.my_label_string = new_text
```

because that is referencing the class `Page1`, but not the instance of that class that is in your GUI. In order to set the `text` in the instance of `Page1`, try replacing the above line with:

```
App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('page1name').my_label_string = new_text
```

The above code gets the `root` of the `App` (which is the `ScreenManager`) and uses that to access the `Page1` `Screen`, and sets the `my_label_string` of that instance. Kivy then takes care of setting the `text` of the `Label` according to your `kv`.

Comment: Thanks ! Its now understandable.